# Pandas multiple dataframes into single

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, concatenation

Been doing a lot of looking into this and still quite find the answer.

I have a list of scraped tables being pulled into Pandas via a `read_html` function. This returns a list of the dataframe objects. I can concat into a single dataframe but the issue is with the format of each of the table pre concat.

I need to Transpose and then concat but not sure how to Transpose when the first step is a `read_html` list of dataframes, the functionality can't work in this format. As a single table it is easy to set a new index and transpose into the exact format, just when in a bulk run that approach wont work. A column is essentially the headers.

The structure is as follows:

`-                                   0                             1
0                                   Id                           470
1                           Nome pozzo          CLARA NORD 004 DIR A
2                             Minerale                           GAS
3                                Stato                 IN PRODUZIONE
4                           Ubicazione                          MARE
5                                Campo                    CLARA NORD
6          Concessione di coltivazione                     B.C 13.AS
7                   Piattaforma marina                    CLARA NORD
8   Centrale di raccolta e trattamento                     FALCONARA
9                            Operatore                           ENI
10                Anno di perforazione                          2011
11                      Profondit\\xe0                       1.872 m`

Desired output partial example:

`Id   Nome pozzo    Minerale  Stato          Ubicazione 
56    ALLI 004 OR   OLIO      IN PRODUZIONE  TERRA`

Single table code snippet:

```
#Table declared
 table = soup.find_all('table')
 table1 = str(table)
 df = pd.pandas.read_html(table1)[0] #limited for example
 df2 = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True) #concat full list of df's
 df.columns = ['header', 'value'] #column header set for transpose
 df = df.set_index('header').T #index set and transposed
```

Hope you get the idea of the horizontal output. Issue is when I transpose the bulk the multiple columns/rows of the label to be the headers appear on every dataframe. There are several hundred dataframes to transpose and make one dataframe

Bulk code:

```
#Table declared
 table = soup.find_all('table')
 table1 = str(table)
 df = pd.pandas.read_html(table1)
 df2 = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True) #concat full list of df's
 df2.columns = ['header', 'value'] #column header set for transpose
```

`-                                  header                        value
0                                      Id                            56
1                              Nome pozzo                   ALLI 004 OR
2                                Minerale                          OLIO
3                                   Stato                 IN PRODUZIONE
4                              Ubicazione                         TERRA
5                                   Campo         MONTE ALPI-MONTE ENOC
6             Concessione di coltivazione                 VAL D\\\'AGRI
7      Centrale di raccolta e trattamento     CENTRO OLIO VAL D\\\'AGRI
8                               Operatore                           ENI
9                    Anno di perforazione                          2004
10                         Profondit\\xe0                       3.830 m
11                                     Id                           588
12                             Nome pozzo                  GELA 109 DIR
13                               Minerale                          OLIO
14                                  Stato       PRODUTTIVO NON EROGANTE
15                             Ubicazione                         TERRA
16                                  Campo                    GELA TERRA
17            Concessione di coltivazione                          GELA
18     Centrale di raccolta e trattamento        NUOVO CENTRO OLIO GELA
19                              Operatore  ENI MEDITERRANEA IDROCARBURI
20                   Anno di perforazione                          1997
21                         Profondit\\xe0                       3.493 m
22                                     Id                           705
23                             Nome pozzo                LUNA 010 DIR A
24                               Minerale                           GAS
25                                  Stato       PRODUTTIVO NON EROGANTE
26                             Ubicazione                          MARE
27                                  Campo                          LUNA
28            Concessione di coltivazione                      D.C 1.AG
29                     Piattaforma marina                        LUNA A
...                                   ...                           ...`

Bulk could be like this:

`Id   Nome pozzo   Minerale   Stato          Ubicazione 
56    ALLI 004 OR  OLIO       IN PRODUZIONE  TERRA`
`Id   Nome pozzo   Minerale   Stato          Ubicazione 
54    test OR      OLIO       IN PRODUZIONE  TERRA`
`Id   Nome pozzo   Minerale   Stato          Ubicazione 
53    test1 OR     OLIO       IN PRODUZIONE  TERRA`

Aim is to create this from the above bulk style.

`Id    Nome pozzo    Minerale  Stato          Ubicazione 
 56    ALLI 004 OR   OLIO      IN PRODUZIONE  TERRA

 54    test OR       OLIO      IN PRODUZIONE  TERRA
 53    test1 OR     OLIO       IN PRODUZIONE  TERRA`

I assume this happens because of the two columns to start with the rows being the desired headers, hence why these are repeated every time as each dataframe will have a column `'header'`.

I believe concat would work if in correct transposed format before. Please note some tables differ in columns, some have as many as 12 and some as little have 9. So for my 12 headings each dataframe value would populate unless that table didn't have that column so would null/naan that cell.

A previous option was to read each table into a df and append to a master but that was rather slow and unusable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Or maybe `df.set_index('0').iloc[:, ::2].T`

Comment: thanks @COLDSPEED I think since `read_html` returns a list of objects setting the index is an issue. `Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
0    object
1    object
dtype: object` I'll see if I can convert the object into something that then I could set the index as 'ID'

Comment: Where are you scraping this data from?

Comment: @coldspeed It's pulling done from a fileshare but its an Italian website, a series of links are opened and the table within each link the html and uploaded in a different process. The list is then parsed from the raw html file

Comment: According to your input, `df.set_index(0).T` should work, and if it doesn't, please explain why.

Comment: @coldspeed I have changed question structure to hopefully be clearer. The issue is that your suggestion works when a single table is in question but for multiple tables contacted that wont work due to the list of df objects that is returned from read_html

Comment: can you use pandas series instead of dataframes?

Comment: @RutgerHofste will look into it, I'm not very experienced with pandas at all so I'll do some research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) return list of DataFrames, so you can loop in list comprehension, [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and transpose. Last after `concat` add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove column name:

```
dfs = [df.set_index(0).T for df in pd.pandas.read_html(table1)]
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).rename_axis(None, 1)

print (df)
    Id    Nome pozzo Minerale                    Stato Ubicazione  \
0   56   ALLI 004 OR     OLIO            IN PRODUZIONE      TERRA   
1  588  GELA 109 DIR     OLIO  PRODUTTIVO NON EROGANTE      TERRA   

                   Campo Concessione di coltivazione  \
0  MONTE ALPI-MONTE ENOC               VAL D\\\'AGRI   
1             GELA TERRA                        GELA   

  Centrale di raccolta e trattamento                     Operatore  \
0          CENTRO OLIO VAL D\\\'AGRI                           ENI   
1             NUOVO CENTRO OLIO GELA  ENI MEDITERRANEA IDROCARBURI   

  Anno di perforazione Profondit\\xe0  
0                 2004        3.830 m  
1                 1997        3.493 m
```

Comment: thanks again! I was semi close in looping through the read_html but hadn't quite thought about setting the index there. Makes total sense now. Thanks

Comment: same to you, hopefully I get more competent at this!